# How to show few elements right alignment and left alignment using Flexbox

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, flexbox, react-native-flatlist

I am new to react native. I have idea about FlexBox, As per I understood, We can show elements either left/right/center alignment only. But, I want to show like below

```
______________________________
  Header       Header  Header
______________________________
Image Text     value1  Value2
______________________________
Image Text     value1  Value2
______________________________
Image Text     value1  Value2
______________________________
Image Text     value1  Value2
______________________________
```

How to show the above layout in Flatlist without taking another flexbox, I have idea about, Using two flexboxes, We can achieve this. But, I want to use only single flexbox. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

    /* this is for the header of the table */

    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
     <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center'}>Header</Text>
     </View>
     <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center'}>Header</Text>
     </View>
     <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center'}>Header</Text>
     </View>
    </View>

    /* this is for the data row of the table */

    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
       <View style={{ flex: 2, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Image style={{ flex: 1 }}></Image> 
          <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>Text</Text>
       </View>
       <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text>Value 1</Text>
       </View>
       <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text>Value 2</Text>
       </View>
      </View>
    </View>
```

You can use a grid like this using flex. If you need you can loop when adding row items to table using  a map function easily.

If you need to use Flat list you can use header component(ListHeaderComponent) to render the header row and user renderItem function to render a single row.
Use something like below on your component.

```
   renderHeader() {
     return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
         <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center'}>Header</Text>
         </View>
         <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center'}>Header</Text>
         </View>
         <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center'}>Header</Text>
         </View>
        </View>
     )
    }

    renderItem({ item }) {
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
           <View style={{ flex: 2, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Image style={{ flex: 1 }}>item.image</Image> 
              <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>item.text</Text>
           </View>
           <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Text>item.value_1</Text>
           </View>
           <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Text>item.value_2</Text>
           </View>
        </View>
    }

    render() {
       return (
         <FlatList
           data={[ { text: 'Text', value_1: 'Value 1', value_2: 'Value 2'} ]}
           renderItem={this.renderItem}
           ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
           contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
         />
       );
    }
```

Comment: So, Should I have to use multiple flexboxes?

Comment: Yes! Within the parent flex box you can use elements and use flex size and align your content as needed.

Comment: Where can I set flatlist in that? Each data in row (cell)

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper I added a sample code to use it if you are using Flat list for this. Hope this helps!

Comment: Up voted your answer, But, In render method how you passing array over there?

Comment: Can you post output of this data?

Comment: You can keep the array in your state and pass it as this.state.data